# Is this definition of distance between two points correct?

Tags: geometry, definition, coordinate-systems

I came across this definition

[image]

but it's confusing to me.

Shouldn't $A$ be $(x_1,y_1)$ instead of $(x_1,x_2)$? Same for $Y$. And even if $A$ was correct like that then shouldn't the formula for the distance be written as $$d(X,Y) =\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}$$

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is a typo and your expression

$$d(X,Y) =\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}$$

is the correct one by direct application of pythagorean theorem.

Comment: What about this proof exercise with solution then? Could he be making the same mistake again? The author writes it like that in other occasions too. https://i.imgur.com/TjBnpJ9.png

Comment: @Cresio Yes also this part contains the same typo! But by your correction the proof works in the same way and it's fine. Maybe there is an "errata corrige" for the book, it seems a quite old edition.